# Generate a ASP.NET 4.x type cookie in a ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm currently working on a .NET Core MVC app that requires the user to login (via cookie auth) then once logged in the user is redirected to a cookie protected full framework MVC app.

My question is, how I can share the cookie between them? The reason I'd like to do it this way is the majority of our sites are full framework apps with the .NET Core one being an exception.

From the research I've done it appears there's an [interop library that will enable full framework applications to read .NET Core cookies](https://long2know.com/2017/05/sharing-cookies-and-tokens-between-owin-and-net-core/), but I've seen nothing on doing it the other way around - making the .NET Core application create a cookie using the old full framework mechanism.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you seen the content at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2 ? namely the  Katana cookie authentication section